# Can I install Ubuntu to a USB3 flash drive to play Steam games?

Tags: live-usb, steam

I'm thinking of buying a 64 GB USB 3.0 flash drive to put Ubuntu 12.10 on.

If I do this, can I then install Steam on the flash drive and play Steam games?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you couldn't: to Ubuntu, the flash drive will just be a normal disk, so any software you install in Ubuntu will work properly.